# Sending data from client to server response_tak = client.request(req) I want to add timeout functionality if response doesn't come in particular time

Tags: c++, timeout, client-server, cpprest-sdk

```
 utility::string_t url = U("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post_info");
 web::uri uri1( url);
 web::http::client::http_client client( uri1);
 web::http::http_request request;
 pplx::task<web::http::http_response> response_task;
 web::http::http_response response;

 request.set_method( web::http::methods::POST);
 request.set_body(jsondata);
 response_task = client.request(request);
 response = response_task.get();
```

If  response doesn't come from `client.request(request);` or if it is taking too much time then My .exe will just wait continiously ? So what should I do ?

`web::http::client::http_client::http_client( const uri &base_uri, const http_client_config &client_config );`

There is this function in cpprestsdk library but nothing much given about this `http_client_config` class's
`utility::seconds web::http::client::http_client_config::timeout()const` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timeout for all requests by creating the http_client_config object and using `void web::http::client::http_client_config::set_timeout ( const T & timeout )`, [docu](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client__config.html#ab13a7fc0e1d2d79abd11ed0da42e35b5). Then you need to give the config class into the constructor as the second parameter, using the method you mentioned `web::http::client::http_client::http_client( const uri &base_uri, const http_client_config &client_config );`

The class `pplx::task<web::http::http_response>` is async, if you call `.Get()` directly it will be blocked. You should either check if the response is already there with

```
bool done = resp.is_done();
```

or use a callback function

```
resp.then([=](pplx::task<web::http::http_response> task)
{
    web::http::http_response  response = task.get();
    ...
});
```

> If is_done() returns false, calling get() will risk blocking the
> thread, which defeats the purpose of using an asynchronous API in the
> first place (it will keep GUIs from refreshing and servers from
> scaling). For this situation, we need to take a different approach:
> attach a handler function to the task, which will be invoked once the
> task completes. We do this using the then() function

[more information](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Programming-with-Tasks)